# pandas - add a column of the mean of the last 3 elements in groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of several columns, which I sorted, grouped by index and calculated the difference between each row and the next one in the group. Next I want to add a column of the means of the last 3 differences. For example:

```
index  A  B    A_diff  B_diff    A_diff_last3mean    B_diff_last3mean 
1111   1  2      0       0               NaN              NaN
1111   1  2      0       0               NaN              NaN                 
1111   2  4      1       2               0.33             0.67
1111   4  6      2       2                1               1.33
2222   5  7     NaN     NaN              NaN              NaN #index changed
2222   2  8     -3       1               NaN              NaN
```

I managed to create such columns using

```
df=df.join(df.groupby(['index'],sort=False,as_index=False).diff(),rsuffix='_diff')
y=df.groupby(['index'],sort=False,as_index=False).nth([-1,-2,-3])
z=y.groupby(['index'],sort=False,as_index=False).mean()
```

but that creates an aggregated dataframe, and I need the values to be merged in the original one. I tried with the .transform() function and did not succeed much. Would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import io
import pandas as pd

data = io.StringIO('''\
group  A  B
1111   1  2
1111   1  2
1111   2  4
1111   4  6
2222   5  7
2222   2  8
''')
df = pd.read_csv(data, delim_whitespace=True)

diff = (df.groupby('group')
          .diff()
          .fillna(0)
          .add_suffix('_diff'))
df = df.join(diff)

last3mean = (df.groupby('group')[diff.columns]
               .rolling(3).mean()  
               .reset_index(drop=True)
               .add_suffix('_last3mean'))
df = df.join(last3mean)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   group  A  B  A_diff  B_diff  A_diff_last3mean  B_diff_last3mean
0   1111  1  2     0.0     0.0               NaN               NaN
1   1111  1  2     0.0     0.0               NaN               NaN
2   1111  2  4     1.0     2.0          0.333333          0.666667
3   1111  4  6     2.0     2.0          1.000000          1.333333
4   2222  5  7     0.0     0.0               NaN               NaN
5   2222  2  8    -3.0     1.0               NaN               NaN
```

Notes:

- Although `index` is a perfectly valid column name, pandas DataFrames have indices too. To avoid confusion, I have renamed that column to `group`.
- In your desired output, you seem to have filled the `NaN`s in columns `A_diff` and `B_diff` for the group `1111` but not for the group `2222`. The first line in your code snippet does not perform such filling. I have filled them all — `.fillna(0)` in the definition of `diff`, but you can drop that if you want.

Comment: Thank you. Would be worth mentioning that it works from pandas 0.18.1 (I needed to update)

Comment: For older versions, `.rolling(3).mean()` has to be replaced with `.rolling_mean(3)`.